# What's the difference between Potential energy ($mgh$) and gravitational potential energy ($-\frac{GMm}{r}$)?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy, planets, approximations

Yeah one is for measuring potential energy between the objects of two masses $M$ and $m$
We recently started studying about gravitation and I'm really confused when swtiching back and forth, or can we derive $mgh$ from $-\frac{GMm}{r}$? we derived $mgh$ through work done formula, he recently referred "Gravitational work" as $mgh$. It's really confusing.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/521412/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/286360/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35878/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The expression mgh assumes that the displacement is small enough that g can be considered a constant.