# What is the significance of a reference point in calculating the potential?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, conventions, approximations

The gravitational potential is given as $$U(r)=-\frac{GMm}{R}$$ where $G$ is the universal gravitational constant $M$ is the mass of the earth and $m$ is the mass of an arbitrary object and $R$ is the distance of the object from the Center of the earth.
and if I’m calculating the potential near the surface of the earth it is $$mgh.$$
$mgh$ is obtained by considering the surface of the earth as zero potential.
Can I obtain the same by considering another point or line or entity as reference? I do not understand the concept of a reference point in estimation of potential.
Is it like when you talk of potential at a certain point you need to specify what is the point of reference?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/286360/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the significance of a reference point in calculating the potential?

It is merely a convenience. You can add an arbitrary constant to the energy without changing the physics. The reference point is usually chosen to make some common subset of problems easier.

---

> The gravitational potential is given as $U(r)=-\frac{GMm}{R}$
> ... and R is the distance of the object from the Center of the earth
> ...and if I’m calculating the potential near the surface of the earth it is mgh. mgh is obtained by considering the surface of the earth as zero potential....

Supposing that $R_e$ is the radius of the earth, you can write:
$$
R=R_e+h\;,
$$
where $h$ is small compared with $R_e$.

You can thus perform a Taylor series expansion in the small parameter $h/R_e$ (small compared to $1$):
$$
U=-\frac{GMm}{R_e}\frac{1}{1+h/R_e}
\approx -\frac{GMm}{R_e}\left(1 - \frac{h}{R_e}\right)
=C + \frac{GMm}{R_e^2}h
\equiv C + mgh\;,
$$
where $C$ is a constant and $g\equiv \frac{GM}{R_e^2}$.

As you mention, you can always redefine the zero of the potential energy by subtracting off the constant $C$:
$$
\tilde U(h) = U - C = mgh
$$

Comment: I understand what you say….but I just had one more thing to confirm though… so what you are saying is that this whole notion of potential is more of a relative kind….where in you measure the potential energy relative to some reference and not so much an absolute one…

Comment: @Orpheus Yes, it is only the energy difference that matters.